# line up the data-points of the graph to the ticks on the x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I wanted to build a line graph that represents data that was collected over a couple of months. I came up with the code below.The problem is that I don't think the line represents the data correctly (or it's not how I wanted it). you see the `path` line doesn't go up to the "4 mo" tick leading the users to believe that the data ends at around 3 and a half a months.

I would like all the vertices(not sure the proper term I guess it could be called the data point visualized) to match up properly to the ticks . so the first data-point should be on top of "1 mo" and the second data-point should line up with "2 mo" etc... And this is very important, the last data-point should be at the end of the graph and month 4 should also be at the end of axis line. right now the line doesn't go the whole width of the svg.

```js
var data = [
  {"quarter" : "1mo", "votes" : 400},
  {"quarter" : "2mo", "votes": 200},
  {"quarter": "3mo", "votes" : 1000},
  {"quarter" : "4mo", "votes" : 0}
]

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
//supposed to get the domain ([0, 1000])
var yscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.votes})])
yscale.range([height, 0])

console.log(yscale(900)) //291

var xscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.quarter}))
.rangeRoundBands([0,width])

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).orient("bottom")


var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d){return xscale(d.quarter) })
.y(function(d) {return yscale(d.votes) })
// .interpolate("basis")

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr({
  "width" : (width + 20),
  "height": height + 20
})

svg.append("g")
.append("path")
.attr("d", line(data))
.attr({
  "fill" : "none",
  "stroke" : "limegreen",
  "stroke-width" : "3px"
})

svg.append("g")
.call(xAxis)
.attr({
  "transform" : "translate(0," + (height) + ")"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shift each of the vertices to the center of the `rangeBand`:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return xscale(d.quarter) + xscale.rangeBand()/2 })
    .y(function(d) {return yscale(d.votes) });
```

You can read more about the ordinal scales [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales).

If you want the x-ticks to start at 0, you can use `rangePoints` instead of `rangeRoundBands`:

```
var xscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.quarter}))
    .rangePoints([0,width]);
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6d7wqeyh/

You can see that the values are getting trimmed. But I think you get the idea.

Comment: Great answer.I see that the data is aligned. Now can you please help me with the other part of the question where the width of the line should take up the width of the svg. right now the line graph looks like it's in the middle of the graph. It should look like it takes up the whole graph.  there shouldn't be any space from the left of the graph to the beginning of the graph. and the same thing about the end.

Comment: Which line do you mean exactly? Is it the x-axis?

Comment: I want the path to take up the same with as the x-axis. Does that help clear things up? and the ticks should still match the data points of course .

Comment: Yes, I think I understand what you want. you want the points to start at 0 and end where the svg ends?

Comment: That sounds right to me. It sound like you understand what I want now.